# Memcached object deserialization

Tags: c#, ruby, memcached, enyim

If an object serialized using ruby and pushed into memcache can it be deserialized using another language like C# (using memcache client)?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on whether you serialized it using a serialization format for which a .NET implementation of a deserializer exists.

If there exists a deserializer, then you can.

If there doesn't exist a deserializer, then you can't.

Of course, if there doesn't exist a deserializer *yet*, you can still write one yourself, or hire someone to do it. Depending on the serialization format, it may be easier or harder to do that. JSON is fairly language-neutral, and thus trivial, Ruby Marshal, Python Pickle, Java Serialization, are fairly closely tied to the language, and thus much harder.